# Does the 3DS have an automatic start-up mode?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

With the original DS, you could turn on the auto start-up mode and the console would load the game cartridge without going through the menu. As I install new games/apps, the menu of my 3DS is getting slower, so I keep pressing 'A' impatiently for some valuable seconds until the game starts loading.

Is there a similar configuration for the 3DS? I have seen [a post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/997614-nintendo-3ds/69527969) claming that Nintendo wants you to have your 3DS always on, but I like turning off my 3DS completely instead of using the sleep mode - I couldn't care less about street pass and such.

Comment: As far as i know theres no "legal" way to do it.

Comment: No, no quick boot to cart mode. As for the other performance... Well... what speed is your SD card? That's a good place to start. I would make sure you're running a high-rated Class 10 card, like one from Patriot or the like.

Comment: @Gigala is the "not so legal" way to do it too terrible and fraudulent to comment it here?

Comment: @BryanC. I'm using the default SD which came with the console, so I guess it's not one of the best. I'll consider investing in a good one. It's a pity not being allowed to take advantage of the traditional instant loading times of the Nintendo handhelds, though...

Comment: @ninten no I just dont know it, it probably involves hacking the system in some way. By the way I also hate that they didn't put an alarm clock on the 3DS (despite the "always have your system on" thing you mentioned)

Comment: @ninten I believe the stock card is only a Class 4 card still. The speed difference to me is noticeable, besides the stock card is so small. I'm running a 32GB card and am contemplating upgrading to a 64GB card the next time I have a few bucks and there's a good sale going on. The minute you start taking 3D pictures and videos, you'll eat up your storage.

Answer (score 2):

No, it does **not** have auto start, because the 3DS has downloadable apps and games, so that you can get to those if you don't want to go straight to the game in the game card slot.